# WCF & Java Interop using WSHttpBinding,

Tags: java, wcf, client, wshttpbinding

I’m trying to get a simple WCF application work with Java Client. Service exposes few simple operations using WSHttpBinding, which it does perfectly.

Now, due to some reason (probably due to incomplete WS-* specifications at Java side) it seems impossible to generate a Java Client for this WCF service hosted on remote system.

However, everything works fine when used with basicHttpBinding.

If you successfully use or have implemented WCF (wsHttpBinding) where it was interoperable with Java/Non WCF client?

Comment: Anyone please. I want to know even if this is possible at all

Comment: I'm curious. What features in WS do you need that aren't in basic? I think I've gotten this to work before, but I'll have to dig through some code to find out.

Comment: @MonkeyWrench The features really doesn't matter here. I am concern with interoperability between Java and .Net frameworks. Seems even WS-* is not able to rescue here.

Answer (score 2):

What are you using in Java to generate the client? Not all frameworks are created equal. :) According to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139285/consuming-a-wcf-wshttpbinding-webservice-in-java), you will need to use [WSIT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have seen issues related to WCF/Java. Basic binding in WCF creates WSDL ver 1.1 while other bindings use 1.2 if my memory servers me correctly.

We have also seen issues that can occur if you reuse the message contract.

Testing the WCF service from XML Spy is a good way to catch such errors.