# Security Token issue with WCF Service with wsHttpBinding Axis2 in Java Client

Tags: java, wcf, soap, apache-axis

I have to use a WCF service in a Java client. I have generated proxy code using Axis2 library. I have successfully configured proxy classes but getting issue when calling WCF service method.

Following is the code in my java client.

```
 ServiceXMLStub stub = new ServiceXMLStub("https://qa1-myservice.com/integration/ServiceXML.svc");
        GetMetadata meta = new GetMetadata();
        meta.setStateCode("WA");
        meta.setUserName("tpstester1");
        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(Constants.Configuration.MESSAGE_TYPE,HTTPConstants.MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_ECHO_XML);
        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(Constants.Configuration.DISABLE_SOAP_ACTION,Boolean.TRUE);
        
        stub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");
        
        
        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setUserName("myuser");
        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setPassword("myp@ssw0rd");
        
        GetMetadataResponse response = stub.getMetadata(meta);
```

Following is the issue I am getting when calling this service from this client.

```
  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the 
action 'http://Integration.ContractsXML/IServiceXML/GetMetadata' is incorrect or because the message 
 contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between 
 bindings. 
 The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To 
 prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the 
 service endpoint's binding.
```

I tested this code in .Net client and it works fine there

```
  ServiceReference1.ServiceXMLClient serviceClient = new ServiceReference1.ServiceXMLClient();
            serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myuser";
            serviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myp@ssw0rd";
            var result = serviceClient.GetMetadata("tpstester1", "SA");
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.programmersought.com/article/26442151573/

Comment: It is with basicHttpBinding. I need for wsHttpBinding

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139285/consuming-a-wcf-wshttpbinding-webservice-in-java)?

Comment: I used this Metro library as well but unable to connect it. May be I am not using right code for it. So desperately looking for solution :(

Comment: Ok I am able to resolve this issue myself after spending a lot of time. I will post solution.